# Can a cointegrated variable be exogenous in first difference in a VEC model?

Tags: cointegration, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

If I have a variable C that is cointegrated with both variables A and B separately, can I use it in first-differenced form as an exogenous variable in a VEC model involving A and B?

Comment: What do you think of the answers you got? You have not accepted any of them; is something still unclear?

Answer (score 1):

> Can a cointegrated variable be exogenous in first difference in a VEC model?

and

> [C]an I use it in first-differenced form as an exogenous variable in a VEC model involving A and B?

There is a difference between (1) a variable being exogenous and (2) justifying inclusion of that variable (or its first difference) on the right hand side of a model equation.
I will not go in the technical details of (1), but here is an illustration relevant for (2). You may have a data generating process such as 
\begin{aligned}
x_t &= x_{t-1} + u_t \\
y_t &= x_{t-1} + \Delta x_{t-1} + v_t \\
z_t &= x_{t-1} + w_t \\
\end{aligned}
with $(u_t,v_t,w_t)$ being i.i.d. random errors. Here $x_t$ is not affected by $y_t$ or $z_t$ and it does not adjust towards them. $x_t$ is only driven by its own error process $u_t$. Meanwhile, $y_t$ and $z_t$ adjust toward $x_t$ (with a lag of one period) and are driven by it. So then if you formulate a VECM for $(y_t,z_t)$, you have
\begin{aligned}
\Delta y_t &= (x_{t-1}-y_{t-1}) + \Delta x_{t-1} + v_t \\
\Delta z_t &= (x_{t-1}-z_{t-1}) + w_t \\
\end{aligned}
and obviously you should include $\Delta x_t$ in the equation for $\Delta y_t$ but not for $\Delta z_t$. (You can trivially modify the data generating process to include $\Delta x_{t-1}$ in the equation for $z_t$ or exclude it from the equation for $y_t$, and its role in the VECM would change accordingly.)

So

> can I use it in first-differenced form as an exogenous variable in a VEC model involving A and B?

The above example shows that doing this may or may not make sense depending on the data generating process. However, you will need to include $x_{t-1}$ in levels in the error correction term. I think it is impossible that it would *not* appear in at least one of the error correction terms for $\Delta y_t$ *and* $\Delta z_t$ if both $(x_t,y_t)$ and $(x_t,z_t)$ are cointegrated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple VECM model looks like $$\Delta Y_{t}=\beta\Delta Y_{t-1}+\Pi Y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t}
 $$

what you are talking about sounds like a simple extension $$\Delta Y_{t}=\beta\Delta Y_{t-1}+\Gamma\Delta X_{t-1}+\Pi Y_{t-1}+\Phi X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t}
 $$

In the above model, the $Y$ variables in levels are cointegrated with $X$. Further, a change in $Y$ depends on changes in $X$. But it does not include any particular model for the $X$'s, so you could consider it exogenous. There is no reason you can't estimate the model parameters with OLS, or other techniques.

That being said, it may not be reasonable to assume that $X$ is exogenous. If $X$ is cointegrated with $Y$, then you may want to revisit the exogeneity assumption. You may as well include it in the VECM.

In addition, user @hejseb provides has provided [multiple](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030440769290019N) [references (*Section 4.6)](http://www.math.ku.dk/~sjo/papers/OverviewPreprint.pdf) that warn that estimating the above model could result in faulty inferences about the cointegrating vector. The author recommends testing the assumption of weak exogeneity of $X$ by estimating the full model.

Comment: You may make an explicit note that you included $X_{t-1}$ not only in first differences but also in levels. Also, since you have not specified how $X_t$ is generated, we cannot know whether it is exogenous, or can we?

Comment: @RichardHardy I added the note about the first differences and levels. On the second, I thought my last little paragraph was making the same point, but I tried to clear it up a little bit. EDIT: your answer does a better job making that point!

Comment: Yours is also helpful.

Comment: Your general "Yes" is not correct, I believe. This is discussed in ch 8 (partial systems) in Johansen's book. It depends on whether the conditional model captures "everything" or not. This is theorem 8.1 in the book. Or would you disagree? Ping @RichardHardy

Comment: @hejseb, for me it is easiest to think with the help of constructive examples. I tried to answer accordingly, with appropriate conditioning (so no general claims). John does it less explicitly, and I agree that starting the answer with an unconditional "Yes" should be avoided.

Comment: @RichardHardy I agree, but it should be tied to theoretically motivated arguments I believe. It seems to me as if your second example does not conform with Johansen's theorem as the cointegrating vector enters the equation for $x$ in any case--thus, if you are estimating $\beta$ but this is in fact included in the equation for $x$ you are missing something.

Comment: @hejseb, sorry, I do not quite understand you. What exactly is the problem there? The data generating process that I chose is so simple that I think I should have done everything correctly; I wonder where I could have slipped. My $x_t$ is generated independently of $y_t$ or $z_t$ so omitting the equation for $x_t$ from the VECM should not be a problem.

Comment: @hejseb I have removed the unconditional yes.

Comment: @RichardHardy It could be as simple as us talking about different things. The OP just asks whether they "can use it", without stating the objective. I'm talking about estimation of cointegrating relations. What's in Johansen's book appears to also be in the 1992 paper "Cointegration in partial systems and the efficiency of single-equation analysis". Its Theorem 1 corresponds to thm 8.1 in the book. With your model (with $X_t=(y_t, z_t, x_t)$, $b$ is non-zero and $\alpha$ is a vector of ones. So the conditional model ($x$) is not weakly exogenous for $\beta$ and shouldn't be excluded.

Comment: @hejseb Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of the book handy and a subscription to get the paper. Why don't you add your point as an answer? If it convinces me, I can either edit mine further or delete it.

Comment: Because it's more fun to nitpick :) No, but seriously, I'm not sure it's correct, it's just something that I recalled when seeing the answers here and surely it should be connected. Unfortunately, the paper I mentioned is too old to have a free working paper version or preprint freely available, so my best finding is the very brief section 4.6 here: http://www.math.ku.dk/~sjo/papers/OverviewPreprint.pdf It's an interesting problem, I think.

Comment: @hejseb, I guess you are right in that we are talking about different things. I am taking the error correction term as given and then think how to construct a VECM, while you want to estimate the cointegrating relationship.

Comment: @hejseb I will add something about that to the answer.